# How do I connect my client and server on Ubuntu?

Tags: reactjs, express, ubuntu

I have an ubuntu instance, and I cloned my client (React-typescript) and server (Express-typescript) in the instance and started running them. Both the client and the server are up and running, however now that they are on Ubuntu, I'm not sure what the endpoints look like.

For instance, locally, I can connect to my server via localhost:4000; however now that they are on Ubuntu, my client is getting an `ERR_CONNECTOP_REFUSED`

What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

You need to setup nginx on you ubuntu,
and write a virtual host file which proxy the incoming request to backend or frontend based on PATH condition,

Then you need to change endpoint in react app to public IP of this ubuntu server.

It's long process,
this blog will help you step by step
https://medium.com/geekculture/deploying-a-react-app-and-a-node-js-server-on-a-single-machine-with-pm2-and-nginx-15f17251ee74

Comment: I see. But would adding a proxy in package.json suffice? Like `"proxy": "http://localhost:4000"

Comment: No you will need to write a virtual host file for nginx, and use nginx as proxy, so you can forward incoming request to frontend or backend server based on if the requested url has /api then forward that request from nginx to backend server else to frontend build

Comment: Frontend code will run in browser, and browser will send request to your localhost, not the server's localhost @code_learner93